# Creating a function with limited number of args in python

Tags: python

I am learning programming, and I am thinking how to improve this code in a more pythonic way.

I have a function with number of arguments. However, any caller of the function can specify the arguments, and depending on the arguments given, I will return the dictionary. The given arguments must be only from the listed arguments.

The code that I have below has so much duplication (I remove carPower, carTime and carLease however it will do the same if/else part) 
How can I improve this?

```
def creating_result(my_struct, 
                carColour=None,
                carPrice=None,
                carGas=None,
                carBrand=None,
                carSpeed=None,
                carOwner=None,
                carPower=None,
                carTime=None,
                carLease=None,
                carEngine=None,
                carType=None
                ):  

     if carColour and isinstance(carColour, list):
        my_struct["carColour"] = { "thekey" : carColour}
     elif carColour:
        my_struct["carColour"] = carColour

     if carPrice and isinstance(carPrice, list):
        my_struct["carPrice"] = { "thekey" : carPrice}
     elif carPrice:
        my_struct["carPrice"] = carPrice

     if carGas and isinstance(carGas, list):
        my_struct["carGas"] = { "thekey" : carGas}
     elif carGas:
        my_struct["carGas"] = carGas

     if carBrand and isinstance(carBrand, list):
        my_struct["carBrand"] = { "thekey" : carBrand}
     elif carBrand:
        my_struct["carBrand"] = carBrand

     if carSpeed and isinstance(carSpeed, list):
        my_struct["carSpeed"] = { "thekey" : carSpeed}
     elif carSpeed:
        my_struct["carSpeed"] = carSpeed

     if carEngine:
        my_struct["carEngine"] = carEngine

     if carPrice:
        my_struct["carPrice"] = carPrice

     if carType:
        my_struct["carType"] = carType

     print "my_struct is ", my_struct

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test 1st caller
    my_dict = {}
    creating_result(my_dict, carPrice=1, carColour="red")

    # test 2nd caller
    my_dict = {}
    creating_result(my_dict, carSpeed="200", carType="SUV", carPrice=300)
```

In case I can not change the list of arguments of the function above, how can I improve the (if/else) of the function above?

Answer (score 4):

In all programming language, it is better that a function's name is a verb, or start with a verb. In your case, I would use `create_result()` instead of `creating_result()`.

One this transformation is done, you would think of a better name for this function as it is quite too generic in its meaning. `create_car()` would be better and more meaningful in your context.

For the parameters you are passing, they should be written following the `snake_name` convention. Meaning, for example, `carColour` becomes `car_color`, `carPrice` becomes `car_price`, ... and so on.

**More** important: Regardless of the purpose of the parameters you are passing to the `creating_result()` function, their number is quite much which thing should lead to creating a class and use them as instance attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! especially for the camel case and wrapping this as a class. However maybe I should simplify the question, in the case I can not change the list of args, how can I improve the (if/else) from the given arguments above?

Comment: You are welcome. Many `if ... else` statements are usually "reduced" by creating a dictionary. There are many posts about that issue on this website ([Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40902/alternative-to-multiple-if-statements))

Comment: I think, in this case, the `if ... else` blocks come from some misunderstanding of what to put in a dict and why. So, "creating a dictionary" will actually not help here ;) They should be removed all together, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Your whole code can be rewritten as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test 1st caller
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict.update(carPrice=1, carColour="red")
    print "my_dict is ", my_dict

    # test 2nd caller
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict.update(carSpeed="200", carType="SUV", carPrice=300)
    print "my_dict is ", my_dict
```

Which seems to be what you actually want :)

Besides the points raised by @Billal already, I don't understand why you are creating dicts that hold one item under the key "thekey". Can you elaborate on the idea behind that? I feel you might have misunderstood something here.

Thinking about this more, maybe it's even simpler and you only want to initialize the dicts like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test 1st caller
    my_dict = dict(carPrice=1, carColour="red")
    print "my_dict is ", my_dict

    # test 2nd caller
    my_dict = dict(carSpeed="200", carType="SUV", carPrice=300)
    print "my_dict is ", my_dict
```